# A question about the set of multiple integers of the unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ a field we define 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
u_r=&\underbrace{1_R+\cdots+1_R}_{r-times}=r1_R\quad r>0\\
u_{-r}=&\underbrace{-1_R-\cdots-1_R}_{-r-times}=-(r1_R)\quad r<0\\
u_0=&0\quad r=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We consider the set $U=\{u_r\}_{r\in\mathbb{Z}}$. The following calculus laws hold 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
u_{-r}=&-u_r\\ 
u_{r\pm s}=&u_r+u_s\\ 
u_{rs}=&u_ru_s.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We suppose that $U$ is finite. 
I can not understand the following statement:
If $U$ is finite exist two integer $h$ and $k$, $h>k$ such that $u_h=u_k$.
Why?
Thanks!

Comment: If $U$ is finite then there are finite number of values $u_r$.

Comment: I can not understand why those two indices exist....

Comment: If there are finite number of values, lets say $n$, then $u_0, u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n$ takes at most $n$ values. By Pigeonhole principle there exists two $k$, $l$ such $u_k=u_l$.

Comment: Classical application of pigeonhole principle.

Comment: If those two indices don't exist, Jack, then $u_1$ is different from $u_2$, right? And $u_3$ is different from both of them, right? And then $u_4$ is different yet, right? And so on – you just keep getting different elements, forever. You get infinitely many elements. But, wait – they told you $U$ was finite! So, ....

Comment: Are you satisfied with these comments, Jack?

Comment: @Gerry MyersonI would have preferred something more formal

Comment: @Gerry MyersonI thought in the following way: If two indices did not exist then the function $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to U$ would be injective, but this is impossible because $U$ is finite.

Comment: That's the pigeonhole principle, as noted in two of the comments. As you wanted something formal, you might have gotten what you wanted by writing, "I'd like a formal explanation," instead of writing, "I can not understand why those two indices exist." Never mind – what's important is whether you now understand the situation, and it appears that you do. All's well that ends well.